# What's the original/most used variant of "If I had a [dollar/dime/quarter/penny] for every time ____ "?

Tags: etymology, phrases

I hear this a lot, even in songs, e.g.

> If I had a bill for all the philosophies I shared
>
> If I had a penny for all the possibilities I presented
>
> If I had a dime for every hand thrown up in the air
>
> My wealth would render this no less severe

I guess it started with one of such variant, and everybody then just began using the others. Am I correct? Which variant is the original or the most used one? Or is it just randomly equivalent?

Comment: The earliest I can find is for a surprisingly large amount. Mark Twain in 1809: [If I had a dollar for every person killed per year in India (by snake-bite), I would rather have it than any other property](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22If+I+had+a+dollar+for+every+person+killed+per+year+in+India%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Comment: ...fwiw, ***dollar*** is 4-5 times more common than ***dime***, which is itself twice as common as ***penny*** in Google Books (***cent*** is virtually non-existent, and ***pound*** is no more common than ***penny***). It's not that Brits don't use it, but obviously Americans like the expression much more than we do.

Comment: @Fumble Fingers But it is still extensively used in Britain 'If I had a quid for every time I'd heard someone say that, I'd be as rich as Rothschild' or some such variant.

Comment: @WS2: Like I said, it's not that Brits *don't* use it. But if you check [*percentage per million words written*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=if+I+had+a+dollar%2Cif+I+had+a+pound&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cif%20I%20had%20a%20dollar%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cif%20I%20had%20a%20pound%3B%2Cc0) in both US and UK corpuses, the US version seems to be several times more common. And most likely the *original* was American, since I don't see the "pound" version until a generation after Twain's first recorded usage.

Comment: @Fumble Fingers I was not previously aware that the expression was coined by Mark Twain. In fact I hadn't realised it was American at all. it just seems part of the furniture in the UK. But then there is an awful lot of stuff like that, going in both directions.

Comment: @WS2: Same here. Until I looked it up, my initial expectation was that it would be of *British* origin, and I thought it would probably have started with *If I had a **penny** for every...* I guess Twain was probably relatively successful/wealthy, so to his mind *a dollar* was an insignificant amount. But actually, his 1809 dollar would be about $20 today. If I had $20 for every time I've ever heard *"If I had a pound..."*, I think I'd be quite well off.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Unless he was remarkably precocious, it wasn't coined by Mark Twain. [Here](http://books.google.com/books?id=MBVOAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA730&dq=%22if+I+had+a+dollar%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=R7VuUt2cOO2v4AOl7YGAAQ&ved=0CEUQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22if%20I%20had%20a%20dollar%22&f=false) is an instance from Google books, written when Mark Twain was only two years old (1837). My guess is that the original form is something like *"if I had an obolus for every ..."*

Comment: @FumbleFingers An 1809 dollar would be worth vastly more than $20 today. At least $100, if not more.

Comment: @WS2: Just in case you didn't digest my previous comment, Mark Twain did not say that in 1809; this was a quarter century before he was born. Google books dating is not always accurate. The earliest actual use I can find is [from 1831](http://books.google.com/books?id=180-AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA194&dq=%22if+I+had+a+penny%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=crluUo_hBMzl4APM8IGADg&ved=0CEQQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22if%20I%20had%20a%20penny%22&f=false).

Comment: @WS2: That would have been my initial assumption, but I did a Google search before posting the comment, and found a site telling me an 1809 dollarit would be worth about $18 today. And [this site](http://www.westegg.com/inflation/) (a different one, but just happened to be first in the list) says it's only $14.

Answer (score 2):

Mathematically speaking, the higher the value of the denomination of money you use, the lower the number of the multiplier has to be in order to reach an impressive amount.

So I would guess that "if I had a penny for each time [EVENT]" implies that [EVENT] happens roughly a hundred times as often as if I said "if I had a dollar for each time [EVENT]".  If this theory is true, you wouldn't need a standard amount, you would just adapt the phrase to the situation.

According to Google ngrams, the current ranking from most popular to least is dollar, nickel, dime, penny, quarter.